# iphone reboots after switching language

Tags: iphone, localization, crash, reboot

I'm developing iphone application with localization in Russian and English languages.
For localization I use Localazible.strings file, and also have a copy of Russian and English set of images.
The problem is: when I switch language and application is running in background, and then I'm trying to run application, it crashes, iphone reboots, and starts rebooting over and over. Only switching off and then switching on helps. After doing it I can run application in any language.
When application crashes debugger says only "program received signal 0".
How can I get reasons of such device behavior? These problem occurs on iphone 3gs with iOS 4.1 (jailbreak), iPad with iOS 4.2.1, iPhone 4 iOS 4.3.3 and DON'T occurs on iPhone 4 iOS 4.2.1.

Comment: Spurious crashes and reboots on a jailbreaked iPhone? Hmmm... probably not caused by the jailbreak....

Comment: maybe you haven't noticed. There are 3 (three) devices I've listed. And only 1 (one) is jailbreaked. Hmmm... probably there is another reason.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the language while debugging an app through Xcode, the app is killed by the system (during the reboot) and the debugger interprets that as a `sigkill`, which is what it is telling you - "program received signal 0".

Because the debugger has seen your app killed, it needs to be stopped from within Xcode before you can run it again, other wise you get what looks like a crash on launch and other such errors like "broken pipe" or "unable to start debugger, maybe it is hung in another process".

You won't be able to test a normal "resume from background" when changing language because changing the language restarts springboard and therefore your app is killed.

If you maintain UI state manually (as used to be required before multitasking) then you can restore it on the next launch of your app and maintain an illusion of multitasking.

Comment: Thank you, but it's ok, I don't need illusion of multitasking. I don't know what to do to prevent crashes and reboots of device.

Comment: Have you tried running the application without Xcode and the debugger and seeing if the same behaviour occurs while changing languages without being connected to the debugger?

Comment: Of course, the same problem. Just don't know where to start for fixing it :(